# System.Windows.Ink.InkAnalyzer on Windows XP

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, handwriting-recognition

I created a WPF application with hand input function.

It works fine on Windows 7 , but it can't work on Windows XP

```
System.Windows.Ink.AnalysisStatus status = theInkAnalyer.Analyze();
if(status.Successful) 
{  
   ...  
}
else
{
   //In Windows XP always get in here
}
```

In Windows XP always return false ?

Could someone know how to fix this problem , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's done.

two package

**Microsoft Windows XP Tablet PC Edition Software Development Kit 1.7**

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20039

**Microsoft Windows XP Tablet PC Edition 2005 Recognizer Pack**

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1601